Sum only distinct rows in Google Looker Studio
I have a table like this on Google Looker Studio Dashboard.



Batch
Students




A
1


A
1


B
2


B
2


B
2


C
2


C
2



I want to show a score card showing 'Total students across all distinct batches', i.e. 1 + 2 + 2 = 5. The normal sum function gives me 1+1+2+2+2+2+2 = 12. But I want to sum students only for distinct batches, i.e. A -> 1, B -> 2, C-> 2.
Is there a way to do this on Looker Dashboard, without having to create a separate pivot/group by table?
Will be grateful for any help.
